# git: start a comment with # when using vim

Tags: git, vim, comments

I usually write git comment by starting with a issue code, like this:

```
#3533: Fixed VIB (Very Important Bug)
```

When I perform a commit from command line I write

```
git commit -a -m "#3533: Fixed VIB (Very Important Bug)"
```

and everything is fine. When I perform a merge, or a interactive rebase, I use vim. After rebasing vim appears and I can add a commit, but lines starting with `#` are considered comments.

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

VIB resolved

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Fri Jun 23 11:31:12 2017 +0200
#
# interactive rebase in progress; onto 7832e4d
# Last commands done (3 commands done):
#    s 536d248 Added space
#    s ae41f15 Removed space
# No commands remaining.
# You are currently rebasing branch 'RM-3539' on '7832e4d'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   VIBfile.m
#
```

So how can I start a comment with `#` character using Vim?

Comment: Looks like you chose a bad naming scheme :-) How about just `3533:` or `Issue #3533:` or `JIRA3533`; you will profit from the latter (that includes the bug system name) if your company decides to switch to another vendor.

Comment: I don't think is bad. It's just a naming scheme. It's not a problem related on how to insert the issue in a commit message, but how can I write with Vim a comment that I can write just fine from the console. Of course I can switch to something like `RM-3539`, but it's a workaround and don't answer the question.

Comment: Isn't the issue that your message is treated as a comment, and therefore you cannot use Vim for that message? The comments just "hide" the boilerplate stuff; I don't see why you would add comments there (that will soon be discarded). Yes, my workaround is not an answer; that's why I didn't post one.

Comment: It's because in all other ways inserting # as first character works, by command line, by git extensions, by git kraken and so on, So the question is how can I insert # as first character in a comment using vim. I don't feel to say to other developers to change the way we write comments only because I've this problem with Vim. Other people don't use Vim and don't have the problem, that's all.

Comment: Side note: this has nothing to do with using *vim*, it's just how Git communicates with *any* editor and *any* human using that editor. Git inserts some comments meant for the human, and then strips those comments back out later, using the comment character you choose (but `#` by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `core.commentchar` config setting for this.  e.g. `git -c core.commentchar=$ commit` would allow you to use `#` in the commit message.  You can also set `core.commentchar` to auto in your gitconfig, and git will use a character that is never at the start of a commit message as comment char.

See also the [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corecommentChar).